# Why does Charles Proxy not work when enabling SSL?

Tags: proxy, charles-proxy

I've searched high and low for the answer to this question, and ended up spending hours on something as simple as enabling an SSL proxy with [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/).

**The issue**
Using Charles, when trying access anything over https, you need to add the domain to the list of SSL enabled domains (or you can just use an `*` to cover it all). [More details here](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/ssl-proxying/).

Well, every time I do that, I am no longer able to view any https pages in my browser. I keep getting a 'no data found' error in Chrome, and a 'ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE' in the network panel of dev tools. Frustrating!

I thought for sure it was the certificate that [can be installed in OS X's keychain](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/), but that didn't work. I then found the the following error in the error log:

```
Could not initialize class javax.crypto.SunJCE_b
```

Hmm. Maybe it's something related to the version of Java running on my Mac? I tried downgrading Java 8 to Java 7, but nope. No luck!

Why?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours and hours of searching, trying to contact their support team, and pounding my head on the hardest surface I could find, I figured this ish out.

Apparently, [this package](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572) from Apple needs installed. I don't understand exactly what it does, but something to do with the version of Java. I did not see this documented ANYWHERE. I ended up installing the trial version of Charles on another machine (just to see if it was something with my machine), and I was prompted to install this. In fact, I couldn't start Charles until I did. Why, on my machine, did I not receive that prompt? No idea. I even reinstalled Charles a bunch of times when trying to troubleshoot, and never got it.

Strange, strange, strange, but hopefully this will help someone else if ever running into this issue.

Comment: This problem started occurring for me after a clean install of High Sierra on the same machine. Unfortunately installing the Java 2017 package does not fix it for me.